# Linear regression in R with if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, categories, lm

I have a dummy variable `black` where `black==0` is White and `black==1` is Black. I am trying to fit a linear model `lm` for the `black==1` category only, however running the code below gives me the incorrect coefficients. Is there a way in R to run a model with the `if` statement, similar to Stata?

```
library(foreign)
df<-read.dta("hw4.dta")
attach(df)
black[black==0]<-NA
model3<-lm(rent~I(income^2)+income+black)
```

Answer (score 3):

If looks like there are a few issues here. First, you've stored all your data in separate vectors `rent`, `income` and `black`. You should instead store it in a data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(rent, income, black)
```

To limit a data frame based on a logical expression, you can use the `subset` function:

```
data.limited <- subset(data, black == 1)
```

Finally, you can run your analysis on your limited data frame (presumably without the `black` variable):

```
model3 <- lm(rent~I(income^2)+income, data=data.limited)
```

Comment: also, subset can be used within the lm call --- lm(...,subset=black==1)

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I just added some more to my above code. Does this still apply if I have my data attached?

Comment: I think most would agree that using attach() is generally a bad idea. better to leave your data in the data frame df and use df$variable calls for specific variables. model3<-lm(df$rent~I(df$income^2)+df$income,subset=df$black==1) should provide the results you're looking for

Comment: Others who are wiser than I have suggested to avoid using subset() in code (more for on-the-fly in the console), so I've tried to get in the habit of just using '['. Thus: `lm(rent~I(income^2)+income, data=data[data[,"black"]==0,])`

Comment: I think my coding scheme is messed up because I cleaned my categories in Stata before importing the data set into R. None of the suggestions seem to work because `levels(black)` reveals `[1] "White" "Black"`. Not sure how to remedy this.

Comment: @rbatt `subset` is fine for interactive use. It is better to avoid it inside functions and loops and just stick with `[`

Comment: @user3339295 Well, if you have a factor simply use `data.limited <- df[df$black=="White",]`.

Comment: I hadn't heard anything negative about using `subset` in code, so I'm interested in hearing more about this. I get that it creates a new copy of part of my data, which is some cases is inefficient. However, would there be any benefit here of using `data.limited <- df[df$black == 0,]` instead of `data.limited <- subset(data, black == 0)`? Could you clarify the cases in which it's best to avoid `subset`?

Comment: @josilber http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/1412059

Answer (score 3):

Why not subset the data before running the model? I personally prefer using a dataframe rather than separate vectors which will make the subsetting easier.

```
df <- data.frame(rent, income, black)
```

Then subset the dataframe, o create another one

```
df <- df[df$black==1,]
```

And run the model

```
model3 <- lm(rent ~ I(income^2) , data=df)
```

Comment: With the added lines of codes you can do

    model3<-lm(rent~I(income^2)+income+black, na.action=na.omit)

Comment: probably best not to use the `black` variable in the new model, since it will be constant in the limited data frame.

Comment: That's right, oversight on my part. Thanks! I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The code written below should do it.

```
model3 <- lm(rent~I(income^2)+income+black, data=df, subset=df$black==1))
```

Comment: you might not even need the `df$`

Comment: Why are you passing data = df into the lm function